# "Connection was reset" after submitting some login forms in all browsers

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, browser, connection

Recently I have a problem in all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer) when I try to login in some websites, it seems posting comments in some other websites including this website also has problem:

In Firefox I receive: **The connection was reset**

In Internet Explorer:  **This page can’t be displayed**

In Chrome: **No data received  ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

Certainly it occurs for specific websites and specific `submits`, otherwise I couldn't submit this question.

I don't know if it is caused by a malware or it is a problem with my ISP or internet connection!

I have NOD32 7 installed and my OS is Windows 8.1., I use **no proxy**.

I cleared cache and cookies of the websites with error in Firefox --> **No effect**

Disabled Antivirus --> **No effect**

Turned off Windows Firewall --> **No effect**

Tried to set the DNS of Wi-Fi manually to 8.8.8.8 --> **No effect**

**Update:** Today the problem was resolved. Then I guess, it was due to the ISP. specially that I am in Iran, and the past days we had the parliament elections!

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Have you checked the Proxy settings to make sure nothing was changed? Or recently installed any new software? What websites is your computer allowing you to connect too without issue? Just trying to get a little more info to break down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It must be an internet connection problem from your computer, you can solve it by following the next steps:

1. Open the CMD with admin. privileges (if you use Win8, 8.1 or 10, press Win key + X >> Command Prompt (Admin).
2. Write the commands below, one by one and in order:

   - ipconfig /release

     ipconfig /all

     ipconfig /flushdns

     ipconfig /renew

     netsh int ip set dns

     netsh winsock reset
3. As the last step, **restart** your computer (the "netsh winsock reset" command will tell you to restart your computer because it's necessary to finish the process).